# Twitter JSON Request Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm using the following code to get a JSON string that I'm going to parse into a table of Twitter statuses.

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/json");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=centrikidcamps&callback=TweetTick&rpp=10");
```

The callback parses them and sets them up - at least it has for the past couple of days. But now I get inconsistent return values. Specifically, sometimes I get TweetTick({"results":[ ... ) which is what I want. And sometimes I get {"completed_in ... which results in a parse error. I got this code snippet from the site below (I'm providing this for credit and as a demo example). Is this a transient Twitter thing? Should I be doing things differently to prevent this? Thanks!

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/jquery-twitter-ticker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/?q=centrikidcampsrpp=10&callback=?',
        function(data){
            var responseObject = data;
        }
});
</script>
```

it will work few times and sometimes not
weird. it looks first response of

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&result_type=mixed&count=5&callback=resx

starts with:

```
resx({"results":[{"from_user_id_str":"291792770","profile_image_url":"http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1442845316/yo_pjj_normal.jpg","created_at":"Fri, 15 Jul 2011 00:42:04 ......
```

and next time it starts with

```
{"completed_in":0.041,"max_id":91667423308156928,"max_id_str":"91667423308156928","next_page":"?page=2&max_id=91667423308156928&q=Twitter%20API","page":1,"query":"Twitter+API","refresh_url":"?since_id=91667423308156928&q=Twitter%20API","results":[{"created_at":"F
```

it's their problem...

Comment: Forgive me, yes, you're right. However, the problem remains. When I was removing the query for the purpose of postng, I accidentally hit backspace too many times and lost the question mark. 

Actually, now it's working consistently but I'm getting the following warning - 

    Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

Comment: Just kidding. It's still failing.

Comment: Same issue. :( Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

I've edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Also, I'm still getting the garbage return string from time to time.

Comment: weird, it looks like they have problem with their api -> http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&result_type=mixed&count=5&callback=resx press F5 few times (edited answer will sometimes work and sometimes won't)

Comment: Okay, that's what I wanted to verify. Thank you so much!

Comment: [Opened separated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701715/why-does-twitters-api-return-garbage-sometimes)