# Why does twitter's API return garbage (sometimes)?

Tags: php, json, twitter, callback, jsonp

If you look [there](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&result_type=mixed&count=5&callback=jsonp) and hit F5 (one each second, 10 times maximally), you'll see that few responses

- don't have jsonp callback
- don't have search response

Is that problem on my side (that URL) or is that just Twitter API's fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely twitter's fault, even the  [official](http://search.twitter.com/api/) [link](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=foo&q=twitter) often returns plain instead of padded JSON.

[2011-07-16] Seems fixed now. Maybe some twitter devs reading here?

Comment: okay, that's what I wanted to know :) isn't there any bug report?

Comment: hehe. HOwever it is still ... strange, sometimes it gives me foo({"completed_in":0.139, at the first place instead of tweets

Comment: @genesis That's not a mistake: The root is an object, and order does not matter in objects, so as long as the `"results"` key is there, it's valid and correct.

Comment: aha. I didn't look into it in depth. I was just answering  random question and I spotted that garbage there :)